# Auto including the section into an (pre-defined) environment

Tags: formatting, environments

There is a coherency problem in the following text (its typesetting). The last paragraph must not be considered as a part of subsect02. For instance it is a kind of conclusion of two approaches covered under two previous subsections.

```
\section{section}
Some text here about what we are going to discuss.
\subsection{subsect01}
Text about this subsection.
\subsection{subsect02}
Text about this subsection.

Some text here, which is not related to subsection02, but to the whole section.
```

I want to make the reader distinguish it from paragraph(s) related to the last subsection by changing the text background color of subsection and section. (Maybe change the font size is better?)

Is there a way to approach the goal instead of adding content like `\begin{...}` and `\end{...}` in code?

Answer (score 1):

Changing text background may not be a good idea and should be used cautiously, especially if you want to apply it to large blocks of text.

Instead, insert a `\medskip` or `\bigskip` before the last paragraph, this will visually separate it from the rest of the text. If the last paragraph holds conclusion or summary of the whole section, then a more distinctive separation with asterisks might be better:

```
\begin{center} *** \end{center}
```

Or even try [the asterism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterism_%28typography%29).

Changing the font size is not a solution: make it smaller, and the paragraph will be considered a remark or just optional to read; make it larger, and it will (a) look odd and unprofessional, (b) conflict with headings.

Comment: I think an environment including all text of section has more readability and customized-capability than just add a vertical skip or leaders, in logic.

Comment: @mayyou: I agree that \begin{section} ... \end{section} would be better, but it is just not done this way in LaTeX2e.  (Maybe LaTeX3 will be different?  In ConTeXt, they now do it the *proper* way;).)

But another way might be to include it as a "Conclusion" subsection (or something like this).  Otherwise, I agree with Andrey.